# How can I add a View button display rule in Dynamics 365 online Ribbon Workbench?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to add a display rule for a view button which is visible when a record selected from view and hidden when record not selected. Which one of the rule types below is appropriate?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Enable rule - `SelectionCountRule` to customize a ribbon/command bar button. If it’s disabled, obviously not going to be displayed (which is like Display rule).

```
<EnableRule Id=”Sample.account.grid.OneSelected.EnableRule”>
  <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo=”SelectedEntity” Maximum=”1″ Minimum=”1″ />
</EnableRule>
```

[image]

[image]

[Read more](http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2015/07/selection-count-rule-display-ribbon.html?m=1)